# Bootstrap Navbar becomes transparent on small screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am new to bootstrap, and trying to create a webpage with a responsive navbar. Everything works as I want it to, just the navbar becomes transparent when the screen gets small enough for it to become a collapsible list. I have searched the Chrome inspector to no avail, and tried everything I could think of. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You'll need to edit your question with the code included, otherwise this will be a hassle to figure out. Please include the minimum amount of code to demonstrate the issue if possible.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. It might take me a while to figure out though. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your css:

```
.navbar{
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Th issue comes from the fact that your row content is created after your navigation (and so in front of it) but you're expanding the navigation on click. To prevent this you just have to give a greater z-index to your nav than to your content (which is 1 by default).

Comment: Thank you so much. I did experiment with z-index, must have done something wrong... I only used it in the chrome inspector.

Comment: It's a common issue with nav tags that expands over the page's content or with fixed navs. Always remember to check in with logical order your tags are placed. Have fun with your website!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just change your scripts.js file or if you don't already have this then add this line of code to your scripts.js. Change the color to what you like accordingly.

```
// Collapse Navbar
var navbarCollapse = function () {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
        $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
        //scroll more than 100 change background color
        //add the same for the else statement below instead of transparent if you dont 
        //want transparent color
        $("#mainNav").css("background-color", "#212529");
    } else {
        $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
        //scroll less than 100 keep background color transparent
        $("#mainNav").css("background-color", "transparent");

    }
};
```